# How many ways are there to put $22$ identical balls into $5$ boxes, with each box receiving at least $2$ balls?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, balls-in-bins

How many ways are there to put $22$ identical balls into $5$ boxes, with each box receiving at least $2$ balls?

The answer is $16$ choose $4$, i.e., $_{16}C_4$, but can someone explain it to me?

Comment: isn't it 26 choose 4?

Comment: Different boxes ? or identitcal boxes ?

Comment: @HeeKwonLee identical boxes.

Comment: It's not identical boxes if the problem is ${}_{16}C_4$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem.  The solution you have presumes that you must put at least two balls in each box.  Is that correct?

Comment: Isn't it at least $2$ per box?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  looks like it.  Fixed.

Comment: If the boxes are identical, the answer is the number of partitions of $22$.

Comment: yes, at least 2 per box, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @SSS fix the question, then.

Comment: @SSS: the Wikipedia article I referenced shows a transformation from requiring at least one to at least zero.  You need a similar transformation in the other direction.  That explains where the $16$ comes from.

Answer (score 1):

As we have at least two balls in each box, we know where 10 of the balls will be, so the question is equivalent to asking how many ways (up to reordering) we can put 12 balls in 5 boxes. This is the same as asking how many ways we can express 12 as a sum of 5 non-negative integers. There are 45 possible ways of doing this:

- 12 = 12+0+0+0+0
- 12 = 11+1+0+0+0
- 12 = 10+2+0+0+0
- 12 = 10+1+1+0+0
- 12 = 9+3+0+0+0
- 12 = 9+2+1+0+0
- 12 = 9+1+1+1+0
- 12 = 8+4+0+0+0
- 12 = 8+3+1+0+0
- 12 = 8+2+1+1+0
- 12 = 8+1+1+1+1
- 12 = 7+5+0+0+0
- 12 = 7+4+1+0+0
- 12 = 7+3+2+0+0
- 12 = 7+3+1+1+0
- 12 = 7+2+2+1+0
- 12 = 7+2+1+1+1
- 12 = 6+6+0+0+0
- 12 = 6+5+1+0+0
- 12 = 6+4+2+0+0
- 12 = 6+4+1+1+0
- 12 = 6+3+3+0+0
- 12 = 6+3+2+1+0
- 12 = 6+3+1+1+1
- 12 = 6+2+2+2+0
- 12 = 6+2+2+1+1
- 12 = 5+5+2+0+0
- 12 = 5+5+1+1+0
- 12 = 5+4+3+0+0
- 12 = 5+4+2+1+0
- 12 = 5+4+1+1+1
- 12 = 5+3+3+1+0
- 12 = 5+3+2+2+0
- 12 = 5+3+2+1+1
- 12 = 5+2+2+2+1
- 12 = 4+4+4+0+0
- 12 = 4+4+3+1+0
- 12 = 4+4+2+2+2
- 12 = 4+3+3+2+0
- 12 = 4+3+3+1+1
- 12 = 4+3+2+2+1
- 12 = 4+2+2+2+2
- 12 = 3+3+3+3+0
- 12 = 3+3+3+2+1
- 12 = 3+3+2+2+2

So there are 45 possible ways of placing 12 identical balls into 5 identical boxes, and hence 45 possible ways of placing 22 identical balls in 5 boxes such that every box contains at least 2 balls.

Answer (score 0):

To add on another answer, you could do this with generating functions. Since you have five boxes, each must have at least two balls, you can find the answer via
$$ [x^{22}]\left( \sum_{i=2}^{22} x^i\right)^5 = \binom{16}{4} = 1820.$$
(Read: get the 22nd coefficient of the following polynomial)